# sed: sed: -e expression #1, char 63: unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to replace a text using sed but facing the following error:

```
[root@server3 ~]# echo "{"playlist":[" | sed 's#{"playlist":[#{"playlist":[{"comment":" text 1","playlist":[#'
sed: -e expression #1, char 63: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` in the pattern so sed doesn't think you're trying to start a character list.

```
echo "test" | sed 's#{"playlist":\[#{"playlist":[{"comment":" text 1","playlist":[#'
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks!